# How to accept SPL-tokens as merchant with Solana Pay?

Tags: spl-token, solana-pay

Perspective: Jr. Dev (1-3 Months)

I am currently working an idea I had with Solana Pay. I wanted the merchant to accept a token other than SOL & USDC. When I began changing variables similar to this tutorial: [Youtube: Solana Storefront with Solana Pay](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TBQA29217Kk). I was met with errors.

**Primary** = What Solana Pay local environment shows me.

```
src\client\components\pages\App.tsx (79:43) @ App


  77 | message={message}
  78 | symbol="STEP"
> 79 | icon={<STEPIcon/>}
     |       ^
  80 | decimals={9}
  81 | minDecimals={1}
  82 | connectWallet={connectWallet}
```

**Secondary** = I just got this one but can still go to the local environment.

```
[{
    "resource": ".../solana-pay/core/example/payment-flow-merchant/constants.ts",
    "owner": "typescript",
    "code": "2307",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Cannot find module '@solana/web3.js' or its corresponding type declarations.",
    "source": "ts",
    "startLineNumber": 1,
    "startColumn": 36,
    "endLineNumber": 1,
    "endColumn": 53
```

}]

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the First Error the Primary One is related to React and not Solana Pay. It looks like you haven't defined what `<STEPIcon/>` is.

Secondary Error:-
It seams like you need to install `@solana/web3.js` cause it's not able to find/detect it.

Comment: I got passed both and trying to pay for it in the app. Only to get stuck in the loading screen. Will keep tweaking around. Thank you for the help!